# Mysql - How can I select rows group by year and month if I have only the timestamp?

Tags: mysql

I have like this data and want to select records group by Year and Month

```
Id      registration_date
1    |  1302566399
2    |  1502745635
3    |  1374679999
```

my query is this

```
  SELECT * FROM tbl_tax_users WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`registration_date`, '%Y') = 2022
  GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(registration_date, '%Y')), 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(registration_date, '%M'));
```

This query select only one month record. this should select 12 months records.
Please help with thanks

Comment: None of the sample dates are in 2022 , can you publish representative sample data please https://dbfiddle.uk/D0PEbpPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output of [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) should be a timestamp, you may compare that output against a timestamp range.  For example, if you wanted records from the 2022 calendar year, you could use:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(registration_date), '%Y-%m'),
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tbl_tax_users
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(registration_date) >= '2022-01-01' AND
      FROM_UNIXTIME(registration_date) <  '2023-01-01'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Blegeleisen thanks but I want to count records for each month so I need Group by month and year

Comment: thanks a lot to resolve my problem please up vote to my question with thanks